# JAVAFX: mouseOver and delay?

Tags: java, delay, boolean-logic

I would like to enable the user to see a description menu when they hover over a collider (which is just a transparent rectangle) for over 2 or 3 seconds. I'm currently using javaFX extensions.

I have the program set to whenever I hover over the collider, it will play a sound effect, but I'd like for it to give a brief description of the object their hovering over IF they have had their mouse over it for at least 2-3 seconds. If that makes sense.

```
benCafCol.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
                    {
                        mediaPlayer.play();
                        benCafBox.setLayoutX(0);
                        benCafBox.setLayoutY(0);
                        benCafBox.setWidth(320);
                        benCafBox.setHeight(35);
                    }
                });

                benCafCol.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent e) 
                    {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();

                        //default terms

                        benCafBox.setLayoutX(5);
                        benCafBox.setLayoutY(5);
                        benCafBox.setWidth(310);
                        benCafBox.setHeight(25);
                    }
                });
```

This compiles- and works, I'd just like for it to do what I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [PauseTransition](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html):

```
Animation delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
delay.setOnFinished(e -> {
    mediaPlayer.play();
    benCafBox.setLayoutX(0);
    benCafBox.setLayoutY(0);
    benCafBox.setWidth(320);
    benCafBox.setHeight(35);
});

benCafCol.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, 
    e -> delay.playFromStart());

benCafCol.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> {
    delay.stop();

    mediaPlayer.stop();

    //default terms

    benCafBox.setLayoutX(5);
    benCafBox.setLayoutY(5);
    benCafBox.setWidth(310);
    benCafBox.setHeight(25);
});
```

Note that `Duration` is [javafx.util.Duration](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/util/Duration.html), not java.time.Duration.

Comment: Thank you so much! that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @KellenMiller If you feel this answers your question, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
Animation delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
delay.setOnFinished(e -> {
    mediaPlayer.play();
    benCafBox.setLayoutX(0);
    benCafBox.setLayoutY(0);
    benCafBox.setWidth(320);
    benCafBox.setHeight(35);
});

benCafCol.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, 
    e -> delay.playFromStart());

benCafCol.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> {
    delay.stop();

    mediaPlayer.stop();

    //default terms

    benCafBox.setLayoutX(5);
    benCafBox.setLayoutY(5);
    benCafBox.setWidth(310);
    benCafBox.setHeight(25);
});
```

this works!